# Blank Screen on Site Search for some Search Terms

Tags: search

We are getting a really odd result when doing certain site searches.

The search function loads a completely blank page when we search for the word Anaerobic; Looking at the source some of the template code is rendered but not all of it.

- Anaerobic – blank page
- Anaerobic digestion – blank page
- Anaerobic Digestion Development Centre – returns results fine

**Failed Search Terms**

```
https://www.uk-cpi.com/search/results?q=Anaerobic+digestion

https://www.uk-cpi.com/search/results?q=Anaerobic
```

**Working Search Terms**

```
https://www.uk-cpi.com/search/results?q=Anaerobic+Digestion+Development+Centre
```

It seems to work fine locally - does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing any caching on this site? If you haven't tried already, clear all the caches and run the query again in  Utilities > Clear Caches

I did some test searches, and it appeared to be the exact search term that's failing rather than content that's returned by that search term, which makes me wonder about a corrupt cache.

Comment: I cleared the cache and this didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the craft logs under storage/logs/ ?
There are quite a few, try doing the following to find out in which logs new stuff is being written when trying your search:

### Linux

1. Check file-dates for all of your storage/logs files

```
# go to storage/logs
cd storage/logs
# view all infos of all the files here
ls -al *
# example output
# -rw-r--r-- 1 your-user domain-user  8452020 Sep 11 11:34 web.log
```

1. Now do a Request which reults in a faulty response.
   and then
2. re-check the dates on last-changed for all your logs, once you find out in which it's being written
3. run `tail -f path/to/file.log` and then
4. watch the output of the console once you do *another* request.

## Windows

1. Simply take a look at the last-changed date on all files through your Explorer
2. Do a faulty-response Request
3. Check the logs which were edited most recently and either
4. a: delete/move said log for it to generate a new one on the next request
   b: Simply take a look at the bottom lines and try to see at which point the output of your faulty-response request beings and take a look there.

If you're able to resolve it through that output, that's great!
If not or you need any other type of help, feel free to respond here and/or open a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the details response - there doesn't seem to be anything showing in the logs.

Comment: Hmm well there's one other thing you can try, you could forcefully add `*searchterm*` asterisks around the search term so as to make craft search quite a bit more leniently (though likely also a decent bit less efficiently).


I tested it out myself and I got lots of results even for the 2nd failed search term you mention in your question. 


To reiterate basically:
`https://www.uk-cpi.com/search/results?q=Anaerobic` 
to
`https://www.uk-cpi.com/search/results?q=*Anaerobic*`


Search Docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/searching.html#supported-syntaxes